# Drag and drop kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am working on an an application in C# with SDK 1.5.

I have two goals:

1. I want to drag shapes, like grab and let it go.
2. If this is possible I need a gesture to grab, like "close finger" to dragging and open five fingers to let it go.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to drag shapes, like grab and let it go.

[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

There are a few examples in the [Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx) examples, including "Shape Game" that show you how to interact with objects on the screen with the skeleton data.  This would be a good starting point for you to see how to extract data from the skeleton and apply to the coordinate system of the application, where other objects can be interacted with.

The "Basic Interactions" example is also a good place to look, though much more complex.

> If this is possible I need a gesture to grab, like "close finger" to dragging and open five fingers to let it go.

The Kinect is not precise enough, when capturing a full body skeleton, to know the state of your fingers.  It knows where your hand is, that is all -- not if your fist is open, closed or any state in-between.

You do not describe the reason for grabbing shapes, so I can not suggest a gesture to "capture" and "release" them.  Using the other hand is one option -- for example, raise the other hand to "capture" and put it down to "release".  There are several other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you coded a working Kinect application before?  Are you able a to follow skeleton movements and work with objects on the screen as you move?  You can try to get ahold of the author and see if he can provide the code, but you should understand the basics first. It is not common that someone will write a whole program for you here.  What specific segment of this issue are you having trouble with.

Comment: ok, i have a button, so when i cliked (hover with the cursor) a new shapes appears, so i want to drag and drop than new shape

Comment: case KinectPaintbrush.Elipse:
                   
                    Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();

            SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();


           mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0);
            myEllipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
            myEllipse.StrokeThickness = 2;
            myEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

            myEllipse.Width = 200;
            myEllipse.Height = 100;
  PART_PaintCanvas.Children.Add(myEllipse);

Comment: Sorry i don´t know how to put the format to the code, but i have a switch and the case kinectPaintbrush.Ellipse generate a new ellipse, so i want to drag and drop that ellipse

Comment: You can edit your question with the appropriate code and concern.  It will make parsing it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need a kinect region in your window which then enables you to handle HandPointers. Those are the variables that can detect if your hand is gripped(in a fist) or not. Like evil closet monkey suggested I would look at the sample projects in the kinect SDK. I have been working on a project dealing with recognizing gestures and utilized a lot of code from those demos.